# What does 125VAC mean on a small indicator bulb?

Tags: voltage

I have recently discovered a small box device that used to have an indicator bulb on it that would switch on when a switch was flicked. I am not sure what voltage to give the bulb, or if its AC or DC, though I assume it is AC because it says 125VAC. This is a picture of the bulb: [image: Bulb]

I am not experienced with circuits at all and I know very little about voltage, amps, resistors, and power supply. What would I need to make this work? Can I use a household battery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That looks like a common neon pilot lamp assembly.  It should work when directly connected to 120 V AC (common household power in the US and Canada).

I've also seen these assemblies using an LED as the light source - but still designed to be connected directly to 120 VAC.

Comment: But why does it say 125 then and not 120?

Comment: @ACD Because household voltage can vary slightly.  In the United States and Canada, [national standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mains_electricity#Standardisation) specify that the nominal voltage at the source should be 120V and allow a range of 114V to 126V (±5%).  Lamps, switches, receptacles, relay contacts etc. are typically spec'ed at 125VAC.